# How to link a Test Result to a Test Case?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I need some how to add a link a `Test Case` with a `Test Result` of this tc.

So, I open the Test Case, go in the `All Links` tab and select `Link to`. In the `Link Type` I choose `Test Result` but the following message appears:

[image]

Now, if I follow the instructions of the message, the test result is already linked with the test case (it is automatically linked when the test result is created). But, I want the other way round. Through the test case to open a specific test result. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the link is there, but you are trying to navigate form the test case to the test results.  I would say that it is a bug that the link to Test Results don't appear in the Links section.

The best I can suggest is to go to the "Test" section (top nav bar), then go to "Analyze Test Runs".  There you can select a test run and for each test case there is a View Results button.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I want the test result to exist as a link in the test case. When a test case fails with `Analysis = Test Issue` then this test case must be reviewed, and I want to have a reference to the Test Result that caused the review.